# Using react-redux with ajax call to API - How to store the API URL

Tags: ajax, api, reactjs, redux

This is a design question when using react-redux. So the data for the react app is coming from a service. I don't want to hard code the service URL since different environments (local, staging and prod) have different URLs. What I am doing now is to have the URL saved in redux store. But it doesn't feel right because store is supposed to record application state, and URL is not part of the state. Is there a "redux" way to handle this?

Comment: Isn't the relative url the same for all. With SuperAgent I don't have to include the server.

Comment: @yiwen My thoughts about this http://jsfiddle.net/ej2hxz90/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using npm dotenv package. It sets env variables from .env file. Once it does in webpack I just need to pass in variables to `React.createElement`.

Once react has the variables, in store I use `thunkMiddleWare.withExtraArgument` to pass in url or whatever other setup variables (pusher instance, for example). Then they can be accessed by an redux-action like

```
return((dispatch, getState, extra) => {
  extra.api...;
  extra.pusher.push...;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it isn't redux concern to now which API address should it use, unless you have to switch them on the fly.

So, the easiest way from my view is to build different build options (through webpack global variables, for instance), which will compile your code with selected API prefix.

And you're right, if something shouldn't be in application store – don't store it there. Work around, through your building tool, precompiling, or some detection in runtime – but generally, your redux code shouldn't have any side-effects, only app state and responding to events.